# Can't get a com port (over usb) to work without opening and closing it once

Tags: c#, serial-port, ftdi

I'm building an application where DMX output is generated. The application than gives this data via an USB interface to the hardware. Since DMX uses the RS485 protocol, almost any RS485 USB-to-Serial converter can be used. I want my application to be extendable by user written plugins, which inherit from my base class which than handles the communication between the application and the interface.
So here is my problem:
I can't communicate with the interface when the interface is plugged in *after* the app was started. Im using `WqlEventQuery`'s and the `ManagementEventWatcher` classes to detect usb event's (plugin & out) and load & unload my classes accordingly. While debugging I noticed that the driver class indeed see's the device, but can't read from it (eg the serial number). Do I need to reset something before the port get's usable?
`status` get's set to `FT_INVALID_HANDLE` after `FT_Open` which means that a communication is never accomplished.
**The FTD2xx class is working as it should be except when the interface is plugged in after starting the app.**

---

**EDIT**
I got it working. However to make the serial usable in my application I have to open, close and dispose it once from the C# `SerialPort` class once. Why is that?

```
var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
SerialPort port = new SerialPort(ports[0]);
port.Open();
port.Close();
port.Dispose();
-> Following code works
```

---

**Code:**
*Bases driver class*

```
public abstract class Driver
{
    public abstract string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract string[] HardwareIDs { get; set; }

    public virtual int FrameRate { get; set; }

    public Driver(int framerate) 
    {
        this.FrameRate = framerate;
    }

    public abstract void Start();

    public abstract void Stop();

    public abstract void SetDMXValue(int channel, byte value);
}
```

*FTD2xx driver class*

```
    public class FTD2XX : Driver
    {
        public override string FullName
        { 
            get { return "FTD2XX Usb-Interface"; } 
            set {} 
        }

        public override string Description
        { 
            get { return "Driver for the FTD2xx usb-to-dmx interface"; } 
            set {} 
        }

        public override string[] HardwareIDs
        { 
            get { return new string[] { @"USB\VID_0403&PID_6001" }; } 
            set {} 
        }

        public byte[] buffer { get; private set; }
        public uint handle;
        public bool done = false;
        public int bytesWritten = 0;
        public FT_STATUS status;

        public const byte BITS_8 = 8;
        public const byte STOP_BITS_2 = 2;
        public const byte PARITY_NONE = 0;
        public const UInt16 FLOW_NONE = 0;
        public const byte PURGE_RX = 1;
        public const byte PURGE_TX = 2;

        Thread workThread;

        // DLL IMPORT'S LEFT OUT FOR SIZE //

        public FTD2XX(int frameRate) : base(frameRate)
        {
            this.buffer = new byte[255];
        }

        public override void Start()
        {
            handle = 0;
            status = FT_Open(0, ref handle);
            workThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(writeData));
            workThread.Start();
        }

        public override void SetDMXValue(int channel, byte value)
        {
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                buffer[channel] = value;
            }
        }

        public void writeData()
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                InitOpenDMX();
                FT_SetBreakOn(handle);
                FT_SetBreakOff(handle);
                bytesWritten = write(handle, buffer, buffer.Length);
                Thread.Sleep(FrameRate);
            }
        }

        public  int write(uint handle, byte[] data, int length)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)length);
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, (int)length);
            uint bytesWritten = 0;
            status = FT_Write(handle, ptr, (uint)length, ref bytesWritten);
            return (int)bytesWritten;
        }

        public void InitOpenDMX()
        {
            status = FT_ResetDevice(handle);
            status = FT_SetDivisor(handle, (char)12);  // set baud rate
            status = FT_SetDataCharacteristics(handle, BITS_8, STOP_BITS_2, PARITY_NONE);
            status = FT_SetFlowControl(handle, (char)FLOW_NONE, 0, 0);
            status = FT_ClrRts(handle);
            status = FT_Purge(handle, PURGE_TX);
            status = FT_Purge(handle, PURGE_RX);
        }

        public override void Stop()
        {
            this.done = true;
            this.workThread.Abort();
            this.workThread = null;
            status = FT_ResetDevice(handle);
            status = FT_Close(handle);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumaration containing the varios return status for the DLL functions.
        /// </summary>
        public enum FT_STATUS
        {
            FT_OK = 0,
            FT_INVALID_HANDLE,
            FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND,
            FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED,
            FT_IO_ERROR,
            FT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES,
            FT_INVALID_PARAMETER,
            FT_INVALID_BAUD_RATE,
            FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_ERASE,
            FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_WRITE,
            FT_FAILED_TO_WRITE_DEVICE,
            FT_EEPROM_READ_FAILED,
            FT_EEPROM_WRITE_FAILED,
            FT_EEPROM_ERASE_FAILED,
            FT_EEPROM_NOT_PRESENT,
            FT_EEPROM_NOT_PROGRAMMED,
            FT_INVALID_ARGS,
            FT_OTHER_ERROR
        };
    }
}
```

*USB event handler*

```
private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
    foreach(Driver driver in this.drivers)
    {
        if (driver.HardwareIDs.Any(hID => (instance.Properties["DeviceID"].Value as string).StartsWith(hID)))
        {
            driver.Start();

            if (this.OnDriverLoaded != null)
                this.OnDriverLoaded(this, new PluginLoadUnloadEventArgs(driver));

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Unplug is basiclly the same, but `.Stop()` and `OnDriverUnload()` used*

*Detecting any compatible usb devices after startup (**Code works as desired if this is the case**)*

```
    ManagementObjectCollection collection;
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
        collection = searcher.Get();

    foreach (var device in collection)
    {
        foreach (Driver driver in this.drivers)
        {
            if (driver.HardwareIDs.Any(hID => (device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID") as string).StartsWith(hID)))
            {
                driver.Start();

                if (this.OnDriverLoaded != null)
                    this.OnDriverLoaded(this, new PluginLoadUnloadEventArgs(driver));

                goto End;
            }
        }
    }
End:
    return;
```